# Enabling the property "isAlwaysOnTopSupported()" in my system

Tags: java, linux, swing

I am working on a GUI  application where we want the property **"setAlwaysOnTop()"** to be true. The property was not getting enabled and on googling it was found that this specific property is not supported in my system which was understood from **"isAlwaysOnTopSupported()"** property which returns false on my existing. I am not able to clearly understand whether this property is related to my "OS" or my "JRE" and how can I make this property support my OS. I have even changed my jre version from 1.6 to 1.7 but that was of no help. I am really stuck here and any sort of help will be really great.

Thank you for your consideration.

PS: The OS that I am currently working on is a specially customised one that is scaled down from "Puppy Linux".

Comment: While the windowing system in linux support (look for example at the fun command `oneku`), java doesn't seem to use this api, and therefore it cannot provide support for the `setAlwaysOnTop` api

Comment: So how would it be possible to make my system support it? The only aim is to make my system support it